# How do I check if an Excel cell's Date is within one week?

Tags: datetime, vba, excel-2010

I'm using VBA in Excel 2010 to make a simple birthday reminder program. I have a column of dates (Column D). How do I check if a cell is within one week of today?

I'm not sure what the VBA syntax for the conditional statement would be:

```
For i = 2 To MAX_ROW
    cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4)
    If (Date(cell) - Date(Now()) <= 7) Then
      MsgBox(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cells contain actual birthdays, you will need to change the year to the current year, say:

```
If DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Cell), Day(Cell)) - Date <= 7 Then
```

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what i needed; i just needed to bound it >= 0 as well, and it works perfectly